# C# SharpZipLib Can't read stream when trying to uncompress zip in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sharpziplib, icsharpcode

I'm using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib to try and unzip a file from the web, all I need to do is get the uncompressed byte array. However I get the error "InvalidOperationException: Unable to read from this stream". I am working in c# in Unity3D with the target as webplayer. It apparently is readable, so I'm not sure of the problem. Here's my code and any help would be very much appreciated.

```
using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s))
    {               

        using (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream zip = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream(s))
        {
            byte[] bytesUncompressed = new byte[32768];
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.Log("can read: " + zip.CanRead);
                int read = zip.Read(bytesUncompressed, 0, bytesUncompressed.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    break;
                zip.Write(bytesUncompressed, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a BinaryReader in the mix here? Given that it buffers the stream, there's a really good chance that it has moved the stream's position to a place you're not expecting it to be; thus giving the appearance of a corrupt or invalid compression.

Comment: Why are you both reading and writing to the same ZipInputStream? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me how you are populating your stream `s`, but all you may need is to roll back your stream's position prior to reading it:

```
s.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Answer (score 0):

The example pattern is fairly painful, let me give you a "better(tm)" pattern to use.

```
byte[] GetBytesFromCompressedStream(MemoryStream src)
{
    byte[] uncompressedBytes = null;

    using (MemoryStream dst = new MemoryStream())
    using (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream zip = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream(src))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int read = -1;

        while((read = zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dst.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        uncompressedBytes = dst.ToArray();
    }

    return uncompressedBytes;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it is still unable to read from the stream, despite .CanRead returning true.

Comment: @normower Are you positive that the source stream has Length > 0? Can you confirm that Position < Length?